# Selecting the first 20 values of a column in a dataframe?

Tags: statistics, julia, subset

I'm wondering how to actually select the first say 20 values from a column in Julia (DataFrames)
for example if i have a vector
data = DataFrame(X=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], Y=[2,4,7,9,10,11,14])
how can I get the first 3 values and the last 3 values of X in a subset?
Source: https://testdataframesjl.readthedocs.io/en/readthedocs/subsets/

Comment: I recommend you to use https://dataframes.juliadata.org/ instead of https://testdataframesjl.readthedocs.io/. The former is an official documentation of the package. The latter is some very old v0.6.0 release of the package from Jan 1, 2015. Since then virtually everything has changed in Julia in general and the package in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `first(x,n)` and `last(x,n)` functions to obtain the first or last `n` values of data `x`. (a vector or a DataFrame). for example:

```
julia> data = DataFrame(X=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], Y=[2,4,7,9,10,11,14])
7×2 DataFrame
 Row │ X      Y     
     │ Int64  Int64 
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      2
   2 │     2      4
   3 │     3      7
   4 │     4      9
   5 │     5     10
   6 │     6     11
   7 │     7     14

julia> first(data,3)
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ X      Y     
     │ Int64  Int64 
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      2
   2 │     2      4
   3 │     3      7

julia> first(data.X,3)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> last(data,3)
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ X      Y     
     │ Int64  Int64 
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     5     10
   2 │     6     11
   3 │     7     14

julia> last(data.X,3)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 5
 6
 7
```

a rationale for using `first` and `last` is found here https://bkamins.github.io/julialang/2021/06/18/first.html