# If I have a vector that was loaded from a CSV and that number has commas separating

Tags: dataframe, csv, statistics, julia, glm

I'm working with a CSV in which one column of numbers is separated with commas (ex. 1,000,000 = 1000000)
Is there a way I can replace the entire column? When I try:

```
replace(df2.Volume, "," => "")
```

it gives me back the entire column as if nothing has changed.
... and when I tried:

```
julia> parse(Int, replace("df2.Volume",","=>"") )
ERROR: ArgumentError: invalid base 10 digit 'd' in "df2.Volume"
Stacktrace:
 [1] tryparse_internal(#unused#::Type{Int64}, s::String, startpos::Int64, endpos::Int64, base_::Int64, raise::Bool)
   @ Base .\parse.jl:137
 [2] parse(::Type{Int64}, s::String; base::Nothing)
   @ Base .\parse.jl:241
 [3] parse(::Type{Int64}, s::String)
   @ Base .\parse.jl:241
 [4] top-level scope
   @ REPL[263]:1
```

The data is all numbers in the millions, so how can I remove these commas??
I appreciate your help!
Source: https://testdataframesjl.readthedocs.io/en/readthedocs/subsets/

Comment: Since there are commas within the column, is this actually a tab-separated file or something else? Or is the column with commas within quotes in the file?

Comment: As commented in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69456535/selecting-the-first-20-values-of-a-column-in-a-dataframe please do not use https://testdataframesjl.readthedocs.io/ as this is a tutorial from 2015 and is outdated.

Comment: there is a [github issue](https://github.com/JuliaData/CSV.jl/issues/626) about this but not much activity on it

Answer (score 2):

A column of a `DataFrame` in Julia is a `Vector`. Hence if you want to do something with the entire column you usually need to vectorize the operation using the dot (`.`) operator.

```
julia> df = DataFrame(Volume=["1,000","1,000,000","1,000,000,0000"]);

julia> df.VolumeOK = replace.(df.Volume, "," => ""); 

julia> df
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ Volume          VolumeOK
     │ String          String
─────┼─────────────────────────────
   1 │ 1,000           1000
   2 │ 1,000,000       1000000
   3 │ 1,000,000,0000  10000000000
```

Note the dot `.` after `replace`.
You can of course further parse it to `Int` using vectorized `parse` function such as `parse.(Int, df.VolumeOK)`.

or parse directly to `Float64` as:

```
df.VolumeOK = parse.(Float64,replace.(df.Volume, "," => ""))
```

Comment: `decimal=` in `CSV.read` is about the decimal separator (eg. `3,14` for pi), not thousands separator. CSV.jl [doesn't have that yet](https://github.com/JuliaData/CSV.jl/issues/626).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
df.Volume = [parse(Int, replace(v, ","=>"")) for v in df.Volume]
```